# How to send message when message size over the limit via WebRTC and libdatachannel

Tags: c++, webrtc, sctp, libdatachannel

I am using libdatachannel library and i want to send file content to answerer.

I have dataChannel but when i sending file content via datachannel, i got error "Message size exceeds limit". i don't know how to split into chunks my message.(setting maxMessageSize is not option because file size changes according to offerer and answerer is browser)

I tried simply;

```
    void sendfile2Content(std::shared_ptr<rtc::DataChannel> dc, const std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring>& files)
    {
        nlohmann::json msg
        {
            {"Message_Type", "File"},
            {"FileName_to_Contents", files}
        };
    
        dc->send(msg.dump());
    }
```

When i call the function i got *std::logic_error*(Message size exceeds limit).

How to send message to peer when message size over the message size limit?

Comment: How to send message to peer when message size over the message size limit or are there another way to sharing files

Comment: In English questions usually end with "?". Please edit your post and (1) show what you have tried so far, and (2) ask a question.

Comment: You will probably have to split the message into smaller pieces manually and combine them at the endpoint. It will require a custom protocol. Which should be used anyway, you should treat webrtc as transport, nothing more.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new so I might say something wrong. But I searched that and I learned SCTP supports PPID-based fragmentation. So I can split message into small pieces just you said. How exactly should I split the message into smaller parts? Should I send new message that contains **"id"** and piece of **msg** (variable in my code) and in the answerer side I combine the message that have this **"id"?** Or is there another way to doing this on datachannel?

Answer (score 1):

Even if data channels support arbitrarily large messages provided the maximum size is negotiated beforehand when establishing the peer connection, you should not send large files as single messages. Instead, you should split them into multiple chunks smaller than the max message size (for instance 64KB),  send them as messages, and reassemble each file at destination.

For instance, you can open a data channel per file (reliable and ordered), send the chunked file as binary messages (possibly with a first text message containing metadata), and close it when finished. The remote side reconstructs the file by appending messages until the channel is closed.

The best practice to prevent gobbling memory is to read the file gradually, stop sending when `bufferedAmount` is over the threshold, and wait for the `onBufferedAmountLow` callback to resume sending.

Answer (score 0):

SCTP (the protocol used by WebRTC datachannels) limits the size of messages to 16kB, and while there exist protocol extensions to send larger messages, they have serious problems, such as not being interoperable between implementations and causing head-of-line blocking.  Thus, you should structure your code to limit messages to 16kB.

In order to implement file transfer over datachannels, you need to manually split your data into 16kB chunks at the sender, and reassemble the chunks at the receiver.  Since the datachannel API predates promises, you will also need to wait for the `onbufferedamountlow` callback in order to avoid overwhelming the socket buffer.

There's an [example in the WebRTC samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/filetransfer/), and there's an [implementation using promises in the Galene sources](https://github.com/jech/galene/blob/master/static/protocol.js#L1981) (disclaimer, I am the author).